# Angular and JQuery Cycle 2 Carousel Collision

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-cycle2

I'm trying to incorporate JQuery Cycle 2's carousel functionality into an angular app.  Everything works fine when I drop the images in the `<div class="carousel">`, but when I use `data-ng-repeat` to list out the images from JSON, the carousel function doesn't fire.

I suspect this is a timing issue, but not sure and not sure how to fix it.

Comment: If you can mock this up in http://jsfiddle.net it'll help. You might also see if the carousel provided by the Angular team works for you:  http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/   Since it's done by the Angular team you might find it integrates better.

Comment: @KayakDave thanks for the link. I looked into angular bootstrap but decided to go with my answer below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, I ended up going outside of Angular and using PHP to draw the images. A lot easier in the shortrun to not rely on Angular for everything :P

Answer (score 0):

try to use cycle slideshow add function :

`$('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('add', '<img src="'+value+'">');`